# Get a list of Google Calendar feeds

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar provides the user with the possibility to create different calendars for the same account (called feeds). These are listed below "my calendars" in the right side of the screen.

Is it possible through the Google Calendar API to get a list of the feeds a user has created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the [CalendarList.list()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) API call.